# AlarmManager en Android 7, la alarma no se ejecuta

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando implementar una alarma en Android, pero no se está lanzando ni un simple `Toast`. Agregué un log para hacerle seguimiento, pero tampoco imprime nada en la consola. El código Java es el siguiente:

**Activity.java**

```
    manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000L, this.pending);
    } else {
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000L, this.pending);
    }
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Hola");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Actualización al 23/03/2019:**

El archivo Manifest solo tiene este permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Además de este receiver

```
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.esw.naughtclock.WAKE_UP"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Tienes registrado el Broadcast en el android manifest?

Comment: Aparte de registrar el Broadcast en el manifest, debes tener los permisos para alarm.SET ALARM y si va a vibrar pues el de VIBRATE